# How to estimate chess engine rating? Year 2023

Tags: engines

Previous [questions](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9536/how-can-i-know-the-elo-rating-of-my-chess-engine) have asked about how to get a chess engine rated. The last one I found was in 2015. It's 8 years since then.

I've started building a chess engine. What's a good way nowadays to get an estimate of the engine's Elo rating?

Comment: @Dheebs That is literally the question that I linked myself in my question. Did you read my question?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the answer to the previous question is out of date? If you don't have any then this question will be closed.

Comment: @Ana that's the method still used.